# Insert value in database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I want to insert value of a table in a database, but only the last row of the table is added to database. I want the whole table value to be added for different rows. I want for each row the new value gets inserted in the database and whole table gets updated by a single click of button. But in my case only the last row is getting updated.

```
    <?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $PersonID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PersonID']);
    $FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
    $Status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Status']);
    $Date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Date']);




    $uname = trim($uname);
    $email = trim($email);
    $upass = trim($upass);

    // email exist or not
    $query = "SELECT Date FROM status WHERE Date='$Date'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result); // if email not found then register

    if($count == 0){

        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO status(PersonID,FirstName,Status, Date) VALUES('$PersonID','$FirstName','$Status','$Date')"))
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('successfully Added ');</script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
            <?php
        }       
    }
    else{
            ?>
            <script>alert('Sorry Attendence already taken ...');</script>
            <?php
    }

}



echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"; 
echo "<html>\n"; 
echo "<head>\n"; 
echo "  <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n"; 
echo "  <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n"; 
echo "  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Blank Page</title>\n";
echo "</head>\n";
echo "<body>\n";


echo "          \n"; 
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM attandance ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"\">\n";
echo "<table border=\"2\">\n"; 
echo "   <tr>\n"; 
echo "      <th>PersonId</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>First Name</th>\n";
echo "      <th>Status</th>\n"; 
echo "      <th>Date</th>\n"; 


echo "    </tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{   
    $PersonID=$row['PersonID'];
    $FirstName=$row['FirstName'];
    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"PersonID\" value=\" $PersonID\"></td>\n"; 

echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"PersonID[$PersonID]\" value=\" $PersonID\"> </td>\n"; echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"FirstName[$PersonID]\" value=\" $FirstName\"></td>\n"; echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" name=\"Status[$PersonID]\" value=\" $Status\"></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";



    }




echo " </table>\n";
echo "<input id=\"button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"btn-signup\" value=\"Submit\">\n";
echo "</form>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
echo "<a href='sheet.php'>Attendence Sheet</a>\n";
echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>\n";
echo "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me why only the last row is getting updated. What should i do in the insert query to update all rows?

Comment: can you show sql from your table?

Comment: I did not get you.

Comment: I am getting the value in the table from database but when i click the button to update values only the last row gets updated.